# How to make cornerRadius on Button edges so that edges are not clipped in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am experimenting with SwiftUI. I do not know how to get a rounded button with a borderWidth. Below is the code that I have tried.

Here is my code

```
struct ArrowButton : View {
    var body: some View {
        return Button(action: {}) {
            HStack {
                Text("SEE ALL")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .color(Color.init(red: 0.627, green: 0.776, blue: 0.965))
                Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                    .font(Font.title.weight(.bold))
            }
        }
            .padding(.all, 9.0)
            .border(Color.init(red: 0.627, green: 0.776, blue: 0.965))
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
    }
}
```

And here is how my view looks 
[image]

What modifiers should i use to

1. Increase the border width?
2. Remove the clipping effect shown below?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `View.border(:width:cornerRadius)` method is not available in the final Xcode 11 version but you can achieve the same result by applying both `cornerRadius` & `overlay` modifiers:

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
    VStack {
        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
        Text("Hello world!")
    }
    .padding()
    .accentColor(Color(.systemRed))
    .background(Color(UIColor.systemRed.withAlphaComponent(0.4)))
    .cornerRadius(4.0)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4).stroke(Color(.systemRed), lineWidth: 2)
    )
}
```

Result:

[image: Button example using the overlay modifier]

Comment: This does not work for HStack, the border is thicker on vertical axis and slimmer on horizontal, looks weird

Answer (score 7):

## Updated for Swift 5 & iOS 13.4+ with Press States!

None of the examples worked for buttons with both dark and white background colors as well as none of them had press state updates, so I built this `LargeButton` view that you can see below.

### Example Photos

[image]

### Example Use

```
// White button with green border.
LargeButton(title: "Invite a Friend", 
            backgroundColor: Color.white, 
            foregroundColor: Color.green) {
                        print("Hello World")
                    }

// Yellow button without a border
LargeButton(title: "Invite a Friend", 
            backgroundColor: Color.yellow) {
                        print("Hello World")
                    }
```

### Code

```
struct LargeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    let backgroundColor: Color
    let foregroundColor: Color
    let isDisabled: Bool
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        let currentForegroundColor = isDisabled || configuration.isPressed ? foregroundColor.opacity(0.3) : foregroundColor
        return configuration.label
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(currentForegroundColor)
            .background(isDisabled || configuration.isPressed ? backgroundColor.opacity(0.3) : backgroundColor)
            // This is the key part, we are using both an overlay as well as cornerRadius
            .cornerRadius(6)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .stroke(currentForegroundColor, lineWidth: 1)
        )
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
            .font(Font.system(size: 19, weight: .semibold))
    }
}

struct LargeButton: View {
    
    private static let buttonHorizontalMargins: CGFloat = 20
    
    var backgroundColor: Color
    var foregroundColor: Color
    
    private let title: String
    private let action: () -> Void
    
    // It would be nice to make this into a binding.
    private let disabled: Bool
    
    init(title: String,
         disabled: Bool = false,
         backgroundColor: Color = Color.green,
         foregroundColor: Color = Color.white,
         action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.foregroundColor = foregroundColor
        self.title = title
        self.action = action
        self.disabled = disabled
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer(minLength: LargeButton.buttonHorizontalMargins)
            Button(action:self.action) {
                Text(self.title)
                    .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
            }
            .buttonStyle(LargeButtonStyle(backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                                          foregroundColor: foregroundColor,
                                          isDisabled: disabled))
                .disabled(self.disabled)
            Spacer(minLength: LargeButton.buttonHorizontalMargins)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a joke that in 2022 this is still what we have to use for a button that fits correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Specify the width and corner radius for the border:

```
.border(Color.init(red: 0.627, green: 0.776, blue: 0.965),
        width: 6.0,
        cornerRadius: 12.0))
```

For example this code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        return Button(action: {}) {
            HStack {
                Text("SEE ALL")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .color(Color.init(red: 0.627, green: 0.776, blue: 0.965))
                Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                    .font(Font.title.weight(.bold))
            }
            }
            .padding(.all, 20.0)
            .border(Color.init(red: 0.627, green: 0.776, blue: 0.965),
                    width: 6.0,
                    cornerRadius: 40.0)
    }
}
```

results in this view:

[image: rounded button]

Comment: It is odd that it works when i add the corner radius in that one border function, but fails when i have the corner radius code afterwards. In anycase, thanks, it works

Comment: @ielyamani, but how do you add cornerRadius to a view and not to a border? This approach doesn't work... :  `Button(action: tap) {
                    Text(optionItem.actionText)
                        .color(Color.white)
                }
                .frame(width: bounds.width * 0.75, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .background(optionItem.color)`

Comment: @AlexShvets The order matters: `.background(Color.red)` and then `.cornerRadius(12)`. A view is still defined by a rectangle even after applying a corner radius.

Comment: Doesn't seem like this function exists anymore.